# JT400 - Equivalent to DSPASPBRM in java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400, jtopen

I try to read the size of an ASP with the java library JT400.
The IBM i (AS400) command to do that is "DSPASPBRM" but I don't find how to do this obtain the same result with the java library.

A solution is to call the command and print the result in a spooled file, and then read the spooled file. But there is maybe a simpler solution.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

See if [Open List of ASPs (QYASPOL) API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qyaspol.htm) has what you need.

Also note that DSPASPBRM is **not** a standard part of the OS.  If you're building a tool for internal use, it might be ok to use.  But if you're building a product for others to use, you can't count of it being there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm building a tool for internal use.
This API seems to have the information that I need but I don't find how to use the API with java code.

Comment: It's a program, you'd call it using the same way you'd call any other server program via JT400.  You'll need to take the handle returned and use it in calls to the Get List Entries (QGYGTLE) and Close List (QGYCLST) APIs.  (also programs)